# The difference between "Here comes the train", "Here the train comes" and "The train comes here"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, difference, usage

In an animation, children are waiting for a train in a station. Someone sees the train and says 'here comes the train'.

My question is, Is there any differences between these sentences:

'Here comes the train.'

'Here the train comes.'

'The train comes here.'

Which one is wrong to use?

Comment: I recommend reading through this question: ["Here he comes." vs. "Here comes he"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/246050/240109)

Comment: Also related but closed as a duplicate,  [“Here comes the Queen” versus “Here the Queen comes”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427322/here-comes-the-queen-versus-here-the-queen-comes)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Here comes the train** is the natural and correct way of saying "The train is arriving now."

**The train comes here** is gramatically correct but has a different meaning: "When the train comes, this is the location it comes to." It does not say anything about whether the train is coming now or in three hours or in four weeks.

**Here the train comes** is not a natural way of speaking; it might be used in a song or poem, but not in a conversation at the train station. It would be most likely to mean "Here comes the train" but could also mean "The train comes here" depending on context.

As Kate Bunting said, if you have already been talking about the train and then you hear it, you can say **Here it comes** (*not* **Here comes it**).

Comment: '**Here comes the train** is the natural and correct way of saying "The train is arriving now."' – I'm not sure if that's quite exactly right. It would sound pretty normal to say, "I'm pretty sure that the train is arriving now," but it would sound really weird to say, "I'm pretty sure that here comes the train." To me, the sentence "here comes the train" seems less like an actual statement of fact and more like an expression of emotion.

Comment: @TannerSwett sure, you can’t arbitrarily slot it into other sentences. But “here comes the train” as a complete sentence is entirely acceptable. Perhaps said with relief (as I did yesterday) after delays and cancellations. Perhaps said by a child just excited to board a train!

Answer (score 17):

"Here comes X" is the idiomatic way of drawing attention to the arrival of a person or vehicle. "Here X comes" would be understandable, but less natural. (We can say "Here he/it comes", though.)

"The train comes here" wouldn't be used to greet its arrival. Speaking of its regular timetable, we might say "The train comes here after calling at Newtown station."

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with randomhead, with a slight alternate meaning for the poetic form.

"Here comes the train" is a statement about timing.  It's saying that, at the current moment, the train is comming.

"The train comes here" is a statement about location.  Its saying that this is a place where the train comes.  It says little about when it may arrive, just that it is along the path of the train.

"The train comes" is definitely a poetic phrasing which is not normally heard in speech.  The valid uses for this phrase that I can think of (as an American English native speaker) all speak to something that cannot be stopped.  "Here comes the train" speaks of the train being on its way, but something could derail it (literally).  "The train comes" is a phrasing that suggests there's nothing that could be done to stop the train.  You could throw your body on the tracks, and it would still come.  It's almost a prophetic phrasing, declaring what the future will be.

Again, this would rarely appear in speech.  I forget my archaic tenses, but it really uses a tense that we no longer use regularly.

Comment: useful response

Comment: ""The train comes" is definitely a poetic phrasing which is not normally heard in speech." Unless you use a pronoun instead of a proper noun. "Here it comes!"